# CopyFile to a custom location, with string conversion problem

Tags: c++

I am trying to make this application copy itself to appdata, which requires the USERNAME, which I already have.

But, for some reason, the file doesn't copy to this place. I tried a lot of string conversion to char, but none of them worked for the `strcat()` and `CopyFile()` functions.

Here is the code:

```
char user[UNLEN + 1];
char Original[MAX_PATH];

DWORD User_len = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName(user, & User_len);

std::string Path("C:\\Users\\");
Path += user;
Path += ("\\AppData\\Other Stuff");

GetModuleFileName(NULL, OriginalFile, sizeof(OriginalFile))

char *PathChr = new char(Path.length() + 1); // Might be wrong but continue...
strcat(PathChr, "something.exe");
CopyFile(OriginalFile, PathChr, NULL);
```

The question is now solved!

Comment: `CopyFile()` requires a fully qualified file name (path + filename) for both the source and destination. You're only providing a filename as the destination. When in doubt, read the documentation.

Comment: `char *PathChr = new char(Path.length() + 1);` -- This allocates a single byte, not what you expected.  Second thing is -- why are you allocating a buffer for this?  Just pass `CopyFile` the `c_str()` of the `std::string` you're dealing with.

Comment: Use debugger and you may see what `OriginalFile` and `PathChr` are.

Comment: why don't just use `std::string` when you're using C++? It's not only faster (avoid the search for null termination in strcat) and also safer (no memory leak like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory for `PathChr`. You are allocating only 1 `char`, not `Path.length()` number of `char`s.  You need to use `[]` instead of `()` when calling `new`, eg:

```
char *PathChr = new char[Path.length() + 1];
...
delete[] PathChr;
```

Alternatively, forget using `new[]`, just use the `std::string` you already created, eg:

```
std::string Path = "C:\\Users\\";
Path += user;
Path += "\\AppData\\Other Stuff\\";
Path += "something.exe";
...
CopyFileA(OriginalFile, Path.c_str(), NULL);
```

But, since you already know the maximum array length up front (UNLEN + 43), you don't need a dynamically allocated string at all, a fixed array will suffice:

```
char user[UNLEN + 1];
char Path[UNLEN + 46];
char Original[MAX_PATH];

DWORD User_len = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName(user, &User_len);

strcpy(Path, "C:\\Users\\");
strcat(Path, user);
strcat(Path, "\\AppData\\Other Stuff\\something.exe");

GetModuleFileName(NULL, OriginalFile, sizeof(OriginalFile));

CopyFileA(OriginalFile, Path, NULL);
```

That being said, the location of the `AppData` folder is user-customizable, so do not hard-code it. The *correct* way to get the actual `AppData` path is to use `SHGetFolderPath()` with `CSIDL_(LOCAL_)APPDATA`, or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` with `FOLDERID_(Roaming|Local)AppData`, eg:

```
char AppData[MAX_PATH];
char Path[MAX_PATH];
char Original[MAX_PATH];

SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, AppData);
LPSTR pDest = PathCombineA(Path, AppData, "Other Stuff\\something.exe");

GetModuleFileName(NULL, OriginalFile, sizeof(OriginalFile));

CopyFileA(OriginalFile, pDest, NULL);
```